# Click on button using UI Automation in Winform application in VC++

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, ui-automation

I want to click on a button using UI Automation. I am using UI Automation in Winform VC++.

Here is my code..

```
 AutomationElement^  Select_connect_button= aeForm->FindFirst(TreeScope::Children,gcnew PropertyCondition(AutomationElement::NameProperty, "Select/Connect"));
InvokePattern^ ipClickButton1 = (InvokePattern)Select_connect_button->GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern::Pattern);
 ipClickButton1->Invoke();
```

but it is showing these Error:

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'System::Object ^' to 'System::Windows::Automation::InvokePattern'

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Windows::Automation::InvokePattern' to 'System::Windows::Automation::InvokePattern ^'
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve these Errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The build error is you convert (InvokePattern) to "InvokePattern^".

In my testing, update the second line to below code will fix this issue:

> InvokePattern^ ipClickButton1 = (**InvokePattern^**)Select_connect_button->GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern::Pattern);

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast with those objects.  Here is one way to do it in C#.  You can get the method names, etc. here.  The various constants you need are in something like:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Include\UIAutomationClient.h
(might be the v7.1 directory instead)

```
public static IUIAutomationInvokePattern elementToInvokePattern(this IUIAutomationElement element)
    {
        var conditionInvokePattern = auto.CreatePropertyCondition(
                                                        WindowsConstants.UIA_IsInvokePatternAvailablePropertyId,
                                                        true);

        var cacheRequest = auto.CreateCacheRequest();
        cacheRequest.AddPattern(WindowsConstants.UIA_InvokePatternId);

        var cachedElement = element.FindFirstBuildCache(TreeScope.TreeScope_Element,
                                            conditionInvokePattern,
                                            cacheRequest);

        var invokePattern = (IUIAutomationInvokePattern)
            cachedElement.GetCachedPattern(WindowsConstants.UIA_InvokePatternId);
        return invokePattern;
    }
```

Looks like constants in the example are from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757483.aspx